# RedHat cockpit and nginx unable to login

Tags: nginx, redhat, cockpit

i'm getting the page when i access via remote machine. RedHat installed in my virtual box. However, when i tried login i hitting 401 Authentication failed error. But i tried login to vm and access the page directly localhost:9090, i am able to login. Please help. Below is my nginx configuration file. I'm not sure which part causing it not allwoing to login.

Below is the code i used

```
server {
    listen       8080;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:9090;
    }
}
```